# VS code editing Java on save

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am typing some class or method, and using line breaks to help me see where everything is, and it keeps getting edited out when I save.  I've tried looking for an answer in the extensions and settings, but can't figure out what might be deleting the new lines.

I'll have something like:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Some code here;
    }
}
```

and it will delete the first line break after SomeClass and after args)
it will edit it to look like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        some code here;
    }
}
```

How do I turn off the editing on save that deletes my new lines?

Here is settings.json:

```json
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.padding.bottom": 5,
    "editor.padding.top": 5,
    "editor.roundedSelection": false,
    "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks": true,
    "javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "editor.renderFinalNewline": false,
    "editor.trimAutoWhitespace": false,
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [],
        "compounds": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share settings.json from vs code?

Comment: Ideally you should be following a consistent style guide within the industry. Opening brackets are never on their own lines in Java

Comment: I agree with @OneCricketeer, follow Java Code Conventions. Opening brackets on a new line look alien to Java coders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type **Save Without Formatting**. Hit Enter(Return) and it should save without applying any formatting. Doing this every time doesn't make sense. So maybe you would like to change the key binding from File -> Preferences -> Keyborad Shortcuts.

The doc talks more on that [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_save-without-formatters)

**EDIT 1: START**

If you happen to have a liking for a particular style(like [eclipse-java-google-style](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml)), you can consider setting up the `java.format.settings.url` option under File->Preferences->Settings -> Java.

You can also create your own formatting profile in eclipse and export the profile as xml file and provide the path to the xml file.

But in order to be able to do that you will first need to install the extension [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java).

**Creating profile in eclipse:**
Generally speaking you create profiles in Eclipse by going to the Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> New -> Brace Positions -> Choose the option you want(perhaps `Next line` is what you are looking for, click on the checkbox to modify all with the same value) -> In the same window you will see the `export button(somewhere top right corner)` -> export your new profile to some safe location of your choice. It will be saved as an XML file.

Copy the full path of the file and paste it in the `java.format.settings.url` section mentioned above.

Having a profile setup will save you lot of time. You will never have to manually format your braces/ indentation or any other piece. Define the formatting once and forget about it.

This profile setup also gives you the privilege of using the default `Save` of VSCode. It will format on save but as per your defined profile.

Kind of Win-Win situation for both you and VSCode's default settings.

**EDIT 1: END**

Comment: This works exactly as I was hoping it would!  Kudos and appreciate the assistance Asif!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Edited the answer to add extra piece of advice that might help you and future readers in the long run

Comment: That is even better!  Thanks again, Asif.  I appreciate your help (knowledge/wisdom too).

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` in VS Code. It will open settings. There disable auto formatting of code, as in below image.

[image]

Comment: I have those both unchecked, as in your screenshot.  Tried this already.  It is still doing that..  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Have you tried restarting IDE after changing?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted the IDE after changing the settings (twice now).